# how to handle \ in query mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a procedure in which I am making query as string then prepare query and execute.

Here is the procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `dim_add_customer`(
IN _customer_id BIGINT(20) ,
IN _first_name VARCHAR(50) ,
)
BEGIN
    SET @_query := CONCAT('first_name = "',_first_name,'"');
    SET @_query := CONCAT('UPDATE customer_detail SET ',@_query,' WHERE customer_id = ',_customer_id);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @_query;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now when I call

```
call dim_add_customer(1,'abc\\')
```

Then there is issue in creating string query.The query it made

```
UPDATE customer_detail SET first_name = "abc\" WHERE customer_id = 1
```

is there any best solution to solve this ?

Comment: are you looking to contain or remove the slashes?

Comment: @Haymaker yes I want to save slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't build the queries by concat.

You should use the parameters in the query like

```
SET @_query="UPDATE customer_detail 
   SET first_name=@_first_name 
   WHERE customer_id = @_customer_id"
```

I'm not sure if you can declare your variables directly from the input parameters like

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `dim_add_customer`(
IN @_customer_id BIGINT(20) ,
IN @_first_name VARCHAR(50) ,
```

)

or you have to

```
SET @_customer_id = _customer_id
SET @_first_name = _first_name
```

CAVEAT: I'm used to the MsSql-way of creating procedures with variables; I might have misunderstood something, but at least creating sql by concat should be your last resort.

Creating queries by concat is the equivalent of

```
x=1
q=concat("y=",x,"+2")
eval (q)
```

instead of

```
x=1
y=x+2
```